# image creation does not give correct results

Tags: opencv

I am able to assign 99 to every pixels using following:

```
Mat img2(50, 50, CV_8UC1, Scalar(99));
```

But not able to assign 100 to every pixel using the following line of code:

```
Mat img2(50, 50, CV_8UC1, Scalar(100));
```

Comment: Works for me. You need to post the shortest possible code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
fprintf(fp, "%4d", img2.at<uchar>(i, j));